# Regex to match unordered list with only one child element

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I try to make a regex that only matches list elements over multiple lines with one `<li></li>` tag.
For example:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Test, Test
    </li>
</ul>
```

this should match, but this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        Test, Test
    </li>
    <li>
        Test, Test
    </li>
</ul>
```

should not.

I already have

```
<ul>(.*?)<li>(?!<li>)<\/li>(.*?)</ul>
```

but this don't have a match at all anymore.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Why do this with a RegExp instead of a DOM parser?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Instead use a proper tool like [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?rq=1

Comment: The reason is i want to replace all lists with one element with p tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Don't use regexes for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Here's how to do it without a Regex:

```
$html = [
'<ul>
    <li>
    Test, Test
    </li>
        <li>
    Test, Test
    </li>
</ul>',
'<ul>
    <li>
    Test, Test
    </li>
</ul>',
];

$previous_value = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

$dom = new DOMDocument();
foreach($html as $list) {
    $dom->loadHTML($list);
    echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('li')->length . "\n";
}

libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($previous_value);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/L7Ptm)

This code parses the HTML itself and gets all of `<li>` elements and then simply counts them.